# how loop if function in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, iif-function

How to repeat the if function in a vba code Hello, all I create a command line using if on a form. But I have trouble writing it over and over again. Is there a proper way to simplify this writing?

```
If UserForm1.checkbox15.Value = True Then
UserForm2.textbox1.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox1.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Else
UserForm2.textbox1.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

If UserForm1.checkbox16.Value = True Then
UserForm2.textbox2.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Else
UserForm2.textbox2.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

If UserForm1.checkbox17.Value = True Then
UserForm2.textbox3.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox3.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Else
UserForm2.textbox3.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

If UserForm1.checkbox18.Value = True Then
UserForm2.textbox4.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox4.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Else
UserForm2.textbox4.enable = True
UserForm2.textbox4.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
```

.... .... .... to textbox660 ...

Comment: This is unreadable, please format your code so it is easier to comprehend.

Comment: I was going to attempt to format your code for you, until I saw the unformatted mess you decided to paste in here. Please [edit] your post and at least **make an effort** to format it properly. As is, it's nothing but a code dump mess.

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble posting the code. Rejected continuously. Code I wrote in notepad ++ then I paste it in browser. Somehow rejected every time I edit ..

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that if you have a form with 660 checkboxes (and presumably as many textboxes) you probably need to redesign the application entirely. It's *possible* to do this (e.g., via parameterized function or subroutine, etc) but it's not very clear what you're trying to do here...

Comment: I created a mapping that in 1 row represented 1 main checkbox. Each row has 22 checkboxes. Overall there are 30 rows of main checkboxes.
And when I try, it turns out the application runs smoothly. Then I make another form that serves to take the value from the form earlier. It's just a checkbox I replace with a text box that will fill in the written value of the mapping.
So if the form that contains the checkbox is true, then the text box on the following form is available for the contents of the value ...

Comment: "form" means UserForm object? It looks like these textboxes are *always* enabled, but you only toggle the BackgroundColor based on the checkbox, is that right?  (NB: it's still not clear what you're trying to do)

Comment: I simplify it. I created two userforms and named userform1 and userform2. On userform1 I create checkboxes, say 100 pieces. Which consists of 10 parent check boxes and 90 sub checkboxes. Then on userform2, I created 100 text boxes, the same as userform1. Function of the text box here, will be active if the check box from userform1 is true, and the text box can be edited

Comment: Please EDIT your question with these details. Doing so bumps it on the front page so that the question gains visibility. See [ask], take the [tour] and consider providing an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your color long values as `Const` outside of the subroutines, at the top of the module.

```
Public Const bgColorTrue As Long = 13158600  '## RGB(200,200,200)
Public Const bgColorFalse As Long = 16777215 '## RGB(255,255,255)
```

Then you can do something like this, which is somewhat more simplified, but still requires enumerating all of the pair of TextBox + CheckBox.

```
UserForm2.textbox1.BackColor = IIF(UserForm1.checkbox15.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
UserForm2.textbox2.BackColor = IIF(UserForm1.checkbox16.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
UserForm2.textbox3.BackColor = IIF(UserForm1.checkbox17.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
UserForm2.textbox4.BackColor = IIF(UserForm1.checkbox18.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
UserForm2.textbox5.BackColor = IIF(UserForm1.checkbox19.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
' etc...
```

Or (assuming the arithmetic relationship between the indexes of the checkboxes and textboxes is constant), you can do a loop and create a subroutine to identify which TextBox pairs with which CheckBox:

```
Dim cb as MSForms.CheckBox, ctrl as Control
For Each ctrl in UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
        Call UpdateForm2(cb, UserForm2)
    End If
Next
```

Using a sub like:

```
Sub UpdateForm2(ByRef cb as MSForms.CheckBox, byRef Uf as UserForm)
    Dim tb as MSForms.TextBox
    Dim iCB as Long, iTB as Long
    '## Get the index of this CheckBox name:
    iCB = CLng(Replace(cb.Name, "checkbox", vbNullString))
    '## Compute the index of corresponding TextBox name
    iTB = iCB - 14
    '## Handle the TextBox on the other UserForm
    Set tb = Uf.Controls("TextBox" & iTB)
    tb.BackColor = IIF(cb.Value = True, bgColorTrue, bgColorFalse)
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i mistakenly wrote the vba code, it should be:

If UserForm1.checkbox15.Value = True Then
UserForm2.textbox1.Locked = False
UserForm2.textbox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Else
UserForm2.textbox1.Locked = True
UserForm2.textbox1.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
End If

... etc

I have tested it and succeeded. It's just that you forgot to add a command to enable the textbox function. 
But your advice is very bright and I can apply. thank you for all